# Copying from an SSD external drive to local drive operates only in bursts and eventually stops

Tags: usb, ssd, external-hard-drive

I have a new gaming-style PC running Windows 11 and a new Samsung T7 Portable SSD drive. When I plug the SSD drive into a USB 3.0 port on my new PC and attempt to copy about 150,000 image files of about 1 Mbyte size in a few hundred folders to the local C: drive  by copying and pasting the folders with TeraCopy, the SSD shows periods of 100% active time when no files are copied, with short periods of less than 100% active time when files are copied. The copy periods are irregular and eventually disappear so the copy process effectively hangs.

If I plug the SSD drive into a 2021 ASUS VivoBook X515DA_M515DA Laptop also running Windows 11, copying proceeds normally, with the SSD drive showing 75% active time. If I plug the SSD drive into one of the ports of a Targus ACH214 4-Port USB hub plugged into the USB3.0 socket of the new PC, copying proceeds with SSD showing 75% active time and a 30 MB/s transfer rate.

Why does using a USB hub allow copying to proceed without hanging on the new PC?

Comment: What kind of drive are you copying to? What make and model?

Comment: If the drive you are copying to is an HDD, particularly one which uses SMR (shingled magnetic recording) then this could well be normal. Those drives need periods of downtime to rearrange data on the disk surface and have a "cache area" that can only accept a particular amount of data before the drive seemingly halts to push data out of the cache. The USB hub is seemingly limiting the speed being written to the drive so that the effect is reduced.

Comment: @Mokubai, you may have nailed it, that USB hub appears to be USB 2.0 spec.

Comment: Destination drive of the new PC is SSD - ADATA Legend 800 according to Device Manager